# Do HTTP DELETEs require Content-Type & Accept Headers

Tags: http-headers

Im currently migrating an old Android application to use Retrofit2

Some of my HTTP calls are DELETEs

While testing I've found my HTTP DELETE calls work fine without Content-Type and Accept headers.

Does HTTP ignore these headers when performing DELETEs?

Is there a Best Practicefor always employing Content-Type & Accept headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Accept` and `Content-Type` are used for deciding which representation of a resource should be sent in the response. With a `DELETE` there generally is no response body, and so there's nothing to decide.

To put it another way, `DELETE` operates on the entire *resource*, so there's no purpose in negotiating a specific *representation*.